# Can Acer Aspire Revo (Atom 330) be used with two monitors simultaneously?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-ion, acer-revo, nettop

I'm so attracted to Acer Revo for the price & the look. As long as I can work on two monitors simultaneously, I'll be happy. Not planning to do heavy video editing or gaming. Occasional movie streaming would be fine. Will mainly use it to do trading, lots of word processing, some photo editing, connecting with friends.

Anyone has experience using Revo with 2 or more monitors? The spec says it has VGA and HDMI output but Acer sales person over the phone told me it can support one monitor only..??

Answer (score 1):

The Aspire Revo AR3610 uses NVidia ION integrated graphics chipset ([specs](http://www.nvidia.com/object/picoatom_specifications.html)).  The chipset hardware supports these displays:

> *Display options:*
>   HDMI, dual-link DVI, DP, or VGA **(any 2)**

Acer has only connected physical ports to the HDMI and VGA outputs, but the chipset is capable of simultaneous output to both.  Now, I don't have direct experience with a Revo, but I do have another ION board in a dual-monitor configuration.

It's also possible that Acer has limited the Revo's capability.  But I suspect the Acer sales guy meant that it only had a VGA output (as "one monitor support"), and considered the HDMI output a "TV output".

The ION won't support more than two monitors by itself, so if you want 2+ monitors you'll need to look into USB video output devices.

Comment: +1 I have one of these at home with two monitors connected, one VGA and one DVI with an HDMI-DVI converter. Works like a charm!

Comment: @fretje: i almost bought one last fall but ended up with a zotac atom/ion board instead.  slightly bigger than the revo, but i got a DVI port and room for a firewire card too.  :)